# If Statements with numerics

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to make it so that when a user types in the word two instead of the numerical 2 that it will tell the user that the number needs to be in numeric form.

```
package monthly.mortgage.rate;

import java.util.Scanner;


class MonthlyMortgageRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Amount;
        double Rate;
        double Months;
        double outputNum1;
        boolean doagain;
        doagain = true;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (doagain) {

            System.out.print("Enter loan amount:");
            Amount = in.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter rate:");
            Rate = in.nextDouble() / 100 / 12;

            System.out.print("Enter year:");
            Months = in.nextDouble() * 12;

            outputNum1 = Rate * Amount / (1 - Math.pow(1 + Rate, -Months));

            if (Amount <= 0)
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
            if (Rate <= 0)
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
            if (Months <= 0)
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
            else
                System.out.printf("Monthly payment is: $ %.2f%n", outputNum1);

            System.out.println("would you like to calculate again?(y/n)");

            if (in.next().toLowerCase().equals("y"))
                ;
            boolean y = doagain;

            if (in.next().toLowerCase().equals("n"))
                doagain = false;
            boolean n = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you think a `;` does at the end of an `if` statement?

Comment: Do you mean something like `in.nextDouble() == 2` as you did earlier in your code?

Comment: If the user types "two" instead of "2" then `nextDouble()` should throw an exception for you to catch... if that's what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

What I'm getting from your question is that you want to find out if someone has typed up a string as a number instead of an int as a number. Basically, you can create an array with every single letter:

```
Array alphabet = {"a", "b"...}
```

Now, just see whether the input contains any of the characters that are in the alphabet...or in our case, the `Array alphabet`. You can use `.contains`

```
for(int i =0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
{
    if(inputString.contains(alphabet[i]))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

That's how you can see whether they typed up any letters, or a string...Like `two` rather than `2`.

**But...The following is probably a much easier method:**

You **don't** want a string as input, right? 
If the user types a string instead of an int then nextDouble() should throw an exception for you to catch.

**So, to take in your input, use a try and catch, and catch the exception for the user not entering a string!**

```
try{
   }Catch(CATCH THE STRING){
System.out.println("You should put in a number!");
 }
```